# How to make constraints constraint to edges with margins in normal mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Let's say i have a super view, v1, and a subview, v2.

and i wish to constraint v2 to v1 in the normal way

```
v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

now, instead of constraining v2 all the way to v1's leading edge, i wish that this code will produce a result whereby v2 is constraining to 10px away from the v1.

Is there any way i can create a super class,v1, that will allow such behaviour?

I don't want the subview to constraint to marginLayout or safeLayout or having a margin parameter in the constraint equation.

Comment: Can you show a pseudo code example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: basically having this line v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.leadingAnchor).isActive = true producing the same effect as v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

Comment: What are you trying to achieve doing that? If you have a lot of code doing the same thing. Then just make a method out of it.